# MVC6 new minification and bundling with Bower/NPM

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gulp, bower

I started getting up to date with the ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6, and I see a lot of internet posts about Bower VS NPM.

- The default started MVC template however uses **both**, is this required for the taskrunner (gulp) to work or is there another reason?
- Second question is about the resource path, in MVC < 6 you could declare a relative path to research the minified/bundled js/css. This way each MVC View would have its own path to its own specific js/css. How can I do this with gulp?
- In MVC < 6 the js/css would NOT minify when debug enabled (as default setting), so it remains readable. I see the option to use an if-like statement on the environment variable like

  environment names="Development">script path

and another one for production in the view. This seems very cumbersome, is there a simple solution for not minifying in debug instead of having to list all paths twice (one minified and one not)?

Comment: Even when running in debug you can have your project reference the built path. Set up gulp with different tasks to minify or not if you need to see it while debugging. Look up gulp watch, I think that is what you are looking for. You will be able to make changes during development and gulp will run tasks for you when your changes are saved.

Comment: thanks, I'm using gulpwatch to compile less on save now, but I don't see how this will help me with 2 scenarios for when debugging the project and when not. Can I see within the gulp.js file if I'm debugging? Then I could use the gulp-if to add minification or not.

Comment: What I mean is all of your paths should just point to the built file, dev or not. Watch will keep updating the built file as you are developing. As far as minification goes you should have a task for that. You could have one version of watch to build it minified and one that doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow (which paths and build file, the destination of the css/js?), what I'm getting is that with Watch I basically create 2 css files (same for js), one minified and one not. and then have the if-statement in the View to determine to use the minified or not? (I prefer to avoid this view-logic).

Comment: You just need 2 tasks. One that minifies and one that doesn't. Then you need 2 versions of watch to call each. Both will build the files and both put those built files in the same place. Your app looks for the files there and doesn't care which version it is. Then you can run which ever version of watch you want to see the js minified or not.

Comment: Yes I get that, but considering both files will build to the same filename, I would have to manually enable/disable a specific watch to make sure the right code ends up in the file, how else will the system know I'm in debug.

Comment: Not exactly, you would really only run the watchWithout during dev and run the task to minify before going to prod. I was just showing you a possibility of running it both ways because i thought that's what you were trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to change an app setting to show one version of the js or the other? That won't work because it is a built js file. You would have to have both versions and an if statement like you are saying wrapped around all paths, which won't work. The only time you should need to see the unminified version is during development. Otherwise just use chromes dev tools to prettify the js with the {} icon.

Comment: right, that's what I thought was needed, just some confusion :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have one version of watch minify your js files and one that doesn't. Either way all of your project paths can just point to the built js file to prevent having to switch back and forth for dev or prod. You would need to break the minify stuff out of the 'scripts' task below and create a task that just does that.

```
//Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('minscripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.alljs, { base: 'public/' })
        .pipe($.concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_build'))
        .pipe($.rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe($.uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.alljs, { base: 'public/' })
        .pipe($.concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_build'))
        .pipe($.rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build));
});

gulp.task('watchWith', function () {
    gulp.watch('public/app/views/*.js', ['lint', 'minscripts']); //<- runs 'scripts' here
    gulp.watch('public/css/*.less', ['less']);
});

gulp.task('watchWithout', function () {
    gulp.watch('public/app/views/*.js', ['lint', 'scripts']);
    gulp.watch('public/css/*.less', ['less']);
});
```

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer question 1 and 2, Ill consider it the answer. For question 2 I'm thinking of creating a folder for each page and just minify those contents per page/folder.

Comment: You could do that although you would lose the benefit of it being a single page app. If you are trying to isolate issues for debugging purposes I would just use logging. If you do want to create a built file for each directory you just need to change the source path: gulp.src(), in the example I added you can see I have the paths in a config file, just set the path or paths you want in that src function which takes an array and you will be able to do what you are wanting to do. You would just need a task for each.

Comment: It's not a single page app, far from it, I think it has about 50-100 actions/views. And ofcourse I wouldnt want all the css/js in 1 big 'site.js' file as shown in de examples. Each page has some shared/common js and some page specific js.